# Running gpt-neo on GPU

Tags: python, gpu

The following code runs the `EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B` model. The model runs on CPUs, but I don't understand why it does not use my GPU. Did I missed something?

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B")


prompt = ("What is the capital of France?")

input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
gen_tokens = model.generate(input_ids, do_sample=True, temperature=0.9, max_length=50 )
gen_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(gen_tokens)[0]
print (gen_text)
```

By the way, here is the output of the `nvidia-smi` command

```
Thu Feb 16 14:58:28 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.108.03   Driver Version: 510.108.03   CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:73:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   31C    P8    34W / 350W |    814MiB / 24576MiB |     22%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA RTX A5000    Off  | 00000000:A6:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 30%   31C    P8    16W / 230W |      8MiB / 24564MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3484      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                378MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3660      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               62MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4364      G   ...662097787256072160,131072      225MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     37532      G   ...6/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      142MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      3484      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The model is based on PyTorch, which means you have to manually move them to GPU. Btw, I recommend using [`pipeline`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines) as `pipeline(..., device=0)`

Answer (score 0):

You should transfer the model and data to GPU like this:

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import GPTJForCausalLM

model = GPTJForCausalLM.from_pretrained("/DCARD/repo/gpt-j-6B", revision="float16", torch_dtype=torch.float16, low_cpu_mem_usage=True).to("cuda")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("/DCARD/repo/gpt-j-6B", revision="float16", torch_dtype=torch.float16)

prompt=("Hello")
input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids.to("cuda")
gen_tokens=model.generate(input_ids,do_sample=True,temperature=0.9,max_length=100,)
gen_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(gen_tokens)[0]
print(gen_text)
```